# Get RCON working on a Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Has anybody been able to get either the rcon or gamespy4 services working on a minecraft server?

Following information on the wiki we've tried:

```
rcon.password=ourverysecretpassword
server-port=25565
query.port=25567
enable-rcon=true
rcon.port=25575
```

But this doesn't seem to enable either service...
The ports are simply closed:

```
Interesting ports on localhost (127.0.0.1):
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
25564/tcp closed unknown
25565/tcp open   unknown
25566/tcp closed unknown
25567/tcp closed unknown
25568/tcp closed unknown
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please explain how you got to see the log?

Comment: You mean the list of ports in the answer above? I used nmap to get that

Answer (score 4):

[Tzarium](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/46431/20163) is not correct reguarding the `nmap` and networking issues. Nmap **is** 100% accurate; though you might need to use it properly and read its output carefully.

`25567/tcp closed` means that **TCP** port 25567 is closed, which is not the same as **UDP** port 25567. And MC server uses UDP for the "query" feature.

Consider these nmap command lines for reference:

```
## Probe UDP port 25565 -- default port for the "query" feature
% nmap -sU -pU:25565 minecraft-server
...
PORT      STATE         SERVICE
25565/udp open|filtered unknown


## Probe TCP ports 25565 and 25575 -- the usual Minecraft client port
## and default RCON port
% nmap -p25565,25575 minecraft-server
...
PORT      STATE SERVICE
25565/tcp open  unknown
25575/tcp open  unknown
```

---

*7 years later edit*

Yea, indeed. "Using nmap properly" includes understanding that *different network paths will behave differently* in general, and especially likely so when you're debugging an issue. To see with nmap what a client sees, **you need to run nmap on the client**; or at the very least from its immediate network neighbor (same local subnet), so that the network path is *mostly* the same except for one host. Notice I wrote `minecraft-server` as nmap target, not `localhost`! — implicitly assuming this understanding. A very late thanks to @user56 commenting on this.

Comment: I'd be very careful calling anything 100% accurate, especially over a loopback address.

Comment: @arda I can't find any way in which the loopback network interface's special implementation could leak through the socket abstraction. Until someone proves this point wrong, I'll stand firm about 100% accuracy.

Comment: One example would be a firewall directly in front of the server.

Comment: @ArdaXi and?.. Yes, a deliberately configured firewall could filter out certain kinds of Minecraft-related traffic, e.g. UDP packets to port 25565. But in that case nmap would show them as **filtered**, not *open*. This is 100% accuracy.

Comment: Nmap wouldn't know, because the loopback device bypasses any firewall that's not software on the device it runs on.

Comment: @ArdaXi it would, if you used it on another machine, following the same traffic path which is causing problems. *Not* on the short-circuited localhost path; this should obvious to anyone. Actually, this is what I meant with words "using it properly".

Comment: Do you know what "loopback" means? Hint: it doesn't involve another machine.

Comment: @ArdaXi Your hypothetical "firewall directly in front of the server" involves another machine. Stop trolling please.

Comment: Let's keep it civil and friendly, please :)

Comment: @ulidtko Yes, exactly. It would involve another machine, making the loopback device useless. Just because you don't understand me does not make me a troll.

Comment: @ArdaXi you don't want to understand me either. I say that if the network path consists of: [minecraft server] - [a router with a firewall] - [minecraft client machine], then nmap launched on the client machine will be 100% accurate in its indications. Nmap launched on the minecraft server will trace a different network path and therefore may not detect network problems which the client machine may have. The latter case doesn't mean that nmap isn't 100% accurate; it means that it should be used properly to be actually useful.

Comment: What I said was is that over a loopback address, nmap would not be 100% accurate. Over a loopback address, nmap can only access the server if it is launched on the server. So yes, it needs to be used properly, ie. not over a loopback interface.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you seem to be checking for open ports with nmap, which isn't 100% reliable (especially when connecting to the loopback address, which your server might not necessarily bind to) On my rcon-enabled server, the rcon port appears to be closed according to nmap, but works fine. A better way to check is using netstat ("netstat -an" works equally well on windows CMD and *nix-based systems) which should show [::]:25575 as "listening"

Have you tried using the [RCON/Query](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/842376-minecraft-server-rconquery-utility/) utility to query the server? remember to try both console (25575 by default) and remote query (25565 by default. You've changed yours to 25567, which really shouldn't matter, but you might consider changing it back, just to be sure.)

If you still can't connect, does the console indicate rcon is enabled when you start the server like so:

> CONSOLE: Default game type: 0
>    CONSOLE: RCON running on 0.0.0.0:25575

If so, what happens when you open a telnet session to your servers IP (preferable not the loopback address), port 25575? You should get a hanging blank window (as opposed to a "connection closed"/"connection refused" message) and an entry in the server console along the lines of "Rcon connection from: /127.0.0.1"